# Standard error of mean of gamma distribution

Tags: standard-error, gamma-distribution

I am trying to determine whether the means of two Gamma distributions are significantly different.  To do this, I am trying to determine the Wald Statistic as

```
Z_0=(Mean_1-Mean_0)/SE(Mean_1)
```

and thence getting the F value using

```
F=Z_0^2/q
```

where q is the number of degrees of freedom.  My first problem is determining the standard error of the mean.

Is the standard error of the mean of a gamma distribution simply the standard deviation divided by the square root of the count, as with a normal distribution?  I have tried to find the answer for this using

```
"standard error" "gamma distribution"
```

and found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30655/a-question-about-parameters-of-gamma-distribution-in-bayesian-econometrics) which initially suggested that the standard error is the same as the variance and was then corrected to say that it is the same as the standard deviation (which would not take the count into account).

Comment: Distributions don't have standard errors, they have standard deviations. A standard error is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of some statistic, but you don't state any statistic. Please clarify your question. If it's the standard error of the mean you seek, the distribution only matters in so far as its variance exists.

Comment: Yes.  It is the standard error of the mean.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I have obtained the SD as the square root of [the shape divided by the square of the rate].  Should I divide that by the square root of the count to get the standard error?  Thanks,

Comment: [See here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92209/can-i-pull-a-confidence-interval-out-of-a-single-sample-by-dividing-it-into-sub/92216#92216) for a derivation of the std error of the sample mean that will apply for any distribution where variances exist.

Comment: If you know the parameters already, you have the whole population distribution already specified. What would you need standard errors of sampling distributions for? Can you explain the underlying problem?

Comment: I have expanded my question to better explain my problem.  Thanks,

Comment: From the link, "The standard deviation of the sample mean is called the standard error of the mean".  Would the denominator for the Wald statistic for a gamma distribution be simply the square root of [the shape divided by the square of the rate]?

Comment: OtagoHarbour - if you *know* the shape and rate parameters, you already know whether the means are different.

Comment: (1) Do you actually have sample estimates of the parameters? (2) If you can assume the shape parameters are the same this might be best done with a GLM.

Comment: why wouldn't you mention you were dealing with GLMs? That's a lot of text. Which bit are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry.  I used the formula on page 409 to get the F value relative to Z_0.  For Z_0, I used the formula on page 385 in section "15.1.1 Estimating and Testing GLMs".  I'm using the mean as the coefficient B_j.  Thanks,

Comment: It looks to me like this is a Chapter from Fox's "Applied Regression Analysis and Generalized Linear Models". Are you actually allowed to give us access to it? [See the recent meta discussion](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2013/am-i-allowed-to-attach-pdfs-of-papers-to-questions) (I imagine it would be okay to quote a small section that's directly relevant.)

Comment: I thought links could not be copyrighted.  However, I have deleted the link just in case.

Comment: I am using the Wald statistic which is the difference between the means divided by the sample standard error.  I understand the F-value is the Wald statistic divided by the number of degrees of freedom. Thanks,